# Can I have an ActionResult called "View"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

**Code:**

```
public ActionResult View(string id)
{ 
   return View();
}
```

I currently get stackoverflow exceptions when I do this.

Comment: I always giggle when I see a stackoverflow exception report on stackoverflow.com :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be getting a compiler warning that your definition of `View` masks that of the base controller class and that you should explicitly use the `new` keyword.  If you change your code to do this instead, it should work as you'd like:

```
return base.View();
```

Answer (score 6):

Of course, just don't call yourself recursively:

```
public new ActionResult View()
{
    return base.View();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's generally a good idea to name your views descriptively. A view named `View` doesn't say what the view does or the data it's likely to use. I would highly suggest giving it a better name.

That said, in this instance, you're recursively calling yourself, so change the return statement to

```
return base.View();
```